# How do I store a db.Blob in Google App Engine's blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

In a python Google App engine app, I can create a `db.Blob` object containing binary data:

```
blob = db.Blob(open("image.png", "rb").read())
```

How do I store that as the value of a `blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty`?

I could create a URL handle and send the blob across a URL, but can I somehow turn the `db.Blob` into a blob store entity directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files API to write files to the blobstore has been deprecated. You have to use GCS instead, because Google is moving away from the blobstore. See this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133)

But your application can also upload your blob to the blobstore of your application. See this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9222732).